# Create a sustainable function which can auto-fill a cell with matching two criteria with a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google Spreadsheets record and generate numbers of table with filtered data. The image is what I am expecting: [Google Spreadsheet expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OYT2.png):

[image]

The first table "List" is the data with ID. The other tables are expected to filter the data.

Take the example in cell A3, the ID is `PM00001`, which is PwC and Facebook. What I am looking for is it will fill cell M3 automatically, since that table is PwC Facebook.

The "List" table will continue develop. So I am looking for a function sustainable for the whole column which I can put in, e.g. cell M3 and able to drag and collect the data from the List table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? what errors do you get? ...http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In cell E3, the function I tried is =index(A3:A,MATCH("EY"&"Facebook",B3:B &C3:C,0))

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `FILTER()` function.
In `E3` put

```
=FILTER($A$3:$A,
        $B$3:$B = $E$1 
        $C$3:$C = E$2)
```

This will filter Column A for all entries where the corresponding row in Column B is equal to the platfrom in row two and the header in row 1.
You can drag this to the right and Column F and G will filter too.
For the other Clients you'll need to change the reference from `E1` to `I1` and `N1` respectively.